# How to populate SelectList with States in Controller Create Action

Tags: razor, html-helper, selectlist, selectlistitem

I am trying to use the code from MS tutorial NerdDinner to populate a pulldown with states, including whatever already exists (for Edit ActionResult).

Here is what was used for Phone Countries in NerdDinner:

```
//ViewData["Countries"] = new SelectList(PhoneValidator.AllCountries, dinner.Country);
```

I have all the States, I just added a few to test. Doesn't work for this helper:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{

    Operation operation = new Operation();

    ViewData["States"] = new SelectList(
        new List<SelectListItem>
        {           
             new SelectListItem{ Text="Ohio", Value="OH"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text="Oklahoma", Value="OK"},
            new SelectListItem { Text="Oregon", Value="OR"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text="Pennsylvania", Value="PA"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text="Rhode Island", Value="RI"}
        }, operation.State);


    return View(operation);

}
```

Here is the helper in the Create View (would be the same as Edit View):

```
@Html.DropDownList("States", ViewData["States"] as SelectList))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of issues. Firstly you build a collection of `SelectListItem` (which is all the `DropDownList` requires) but then try to make a `SelectList` from it. Apart from being pointless extra overhead, your not specifying the `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` parameters so your generating a whole lot of options which would look like

```
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
```

and the second parameter where you attempt to set the selected option will also not work (unless `operation.State` was typeof `SelectListItem`)

Secondly, you cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList`. Your `SelectList` should be named (say) `StateList`

Finally, your not actually binding to anything. Your model contains a property named `State`, not `States`. Always use the strongly typed html helpers.

Your code should be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Operation operation = new Operation();
    ViewData["StateList"] = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {           
        new SelectListItem{ Text="Ohio", Value="OH"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text="Oklahoma", Value="OK"},
        ....
    };
    return View(operation);
}
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StateList"])
```

In your case the first option ("Ohio") will be selected because the value of `State` is `null` and does not match one of your options. If you were to use `operation.State = "OR";` in the controller, then the 3rd option ("Oregon") will be selected when you first render the view.

Comment: Hey thanks a whole bunch. I put this: new SelectListItem{Text ="", Value=""}, at the top of the items so there would be nothing selected. Hope that is the way to do it. Also, I don't understand where to put in the controller how to set the item selected. For the Create view it would be probably hardcoded to "OR" like you mention, but on the Edit screen it would use the value in the operation.State column. I will make this the answer however.

Comment: No, If you want a 'default' (`null`) item, then use `Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StateList"], "-Please select-")` - the 3 parameter add `<option value="">-Please select-</option>` which if selected will post back `null` (and if you have a `[Required]` attribute on `State` will cause a validation error

Comment: In a create view, you would not set the value of `State` so that the "-Please select-" option will be selected. For an edit view, if your using EF to populate the model, then the value of `State` will already be set so you don't need to do anything. If you still having problems, post a new question showing the `Edit()` method.

Comment: Ok, your list helper worked in the Edit view to return the correct value saved in the table's State column. There are other errors if I unselect the pulldown but I figure that is enough stuff for another quesition. thank you again.

Comment: So I got it working but get an error. . . . I put this. . . . . @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StateList"],"-Please Select-") . . . .I get this error when I try saving with nothing selected ("-Please Select-"). . . . .  System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'State'.

Comment: You really need to ask a new question with the relevant code, but it looks like you are returning the view in the POST method because `ModelState` is invalid, in which case you need to re-assign the `SelectList` (just as you did in the GET method) before you return the view, otherwise `ViewData["StateList"]` is `null`

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I took it a step farther using other StackOverflow links and made a public class in my controller and use it now efficiently. Here is the new question and accepted answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032258/view-doesnt-see-class-and-public-static)