# View doesn't see class and public static

Tags: razor, selectlist, selectlistitem

This is my helper in my View. (I want to list state choices in pulldown).

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, SelectListItemHelper.GetStateList())
```

I get this error: 
 CS0103: The name 'SelectListItemHelper' does not exist in the current context

I put this class in my one and only controller that has all my Create, Edit, Delete Action Results. I made another public class below it. Used this link for my states info: [How To Create Select List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539149/how-to-create-select-list-for-country-and-states-province-in-mvc)

```
public class SelectListItemHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStateList()
    {
        IList<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem() {Text="Alabama", Value="AL"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Alaska", Value="AK"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Arizona", Value="AZ"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Arkansas", Value="AR"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="California", Value="CA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Colorado", Value="CO"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Connecticut", Value="CT"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="District of Columbia", Value="DC"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Delaware", Value="DE"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Florida", Value="FL"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Georgia", Value="GA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Hawaii", Value="HI"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Idaho", Value="ID"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Illinois", Value="IL"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Indiana", Value="IN"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Iowa", Value="IA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Kansas", Value="KS"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Kentucky", Value="KY"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Louisiana", Value="LA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Maine", Value="ME"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Maryland", Value="MD"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Massachusetts", Value="MA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Michigan", Value="MI"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Minnesota", Value="MN"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Mississippi", Value="MS"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Missouri", Value="MO"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Montana", Value="MT"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Nebraska", Value="NE"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Nevada", Value="NV"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="New Hampshire", Value="NH"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="New Jersey", Value="NJ"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="New Mexico", Value="NM"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="New York", Value="NY"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="North Carolina", Value="NC"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="North Dakota", Value="ND"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Ohio", Value="OH"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Oklahoma", Value="OK"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Oregon", Value="OR"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Pennsylvania", Value="PA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Rhode Island", Value="RI"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="South Carolina", Value="SC"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="South Dakota", Value="SD"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Tennessee", Value="TN"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Texas", Value="TX"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Utah", Value="UT"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Vermont", Value="VT"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Virginia", Value="VA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Washington", Value="WA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="West Virginia", Value="WV"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Wisconsin", Value="WI"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Wyoming", Value="WY"}
        };
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the namespace of your class? you need to include the name space in your view

Comment: Either prefix `SelectListItemHelper` with the namespace it's in, or add a `using` statement in the view

Comment: Ala, if you make this an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer. I just added "Radius.Controllers." to the front of the SelectListItemHelper.GetStateList() and it worked. thank you

Comment: Ha, I googled this problem because I had it again for something new. Shows how crazy I am (and also how much I depend on StackOverflow).
3dd,  if you want to make your comment an answer I will accept it. I guess Ala isn't interested. I actually tried adding your "using" solution to the view up at the top and it worked! Gotta love StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your view doesn't know about code that exists only in your controller. Easiest fix is to call get state list in your controller and pass in a list of SelectListItem to your view. If your view is now bound to SomeModel, make a ViewModel SomeViewModel with two fields, SomeModel MyModel and List States, and bind to Some View Model in your view.